# asp:DropDownList requires double click to select value

Tags: javascript, c#, html, asp.net

I have following drop down:

```
<asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="Group" CssClass="form-control" Enabled="True"  onChange="javascript:loadDat();">
<asp:ListItem Text="Select a Field Group..." />
</asp:DropDownList>
```

For some reason, when I'm in Internet Explorer 11, it requires two clicks for me to open it up and see the options, which is just an extra click for the end-user. It works fine in Google Chrome, Mozilla Firefox and Safari: I only have to click once to see the options for a selection. Why would it not work correctly in IE? And more importantly, how can I fix it in IE?

Comment: Is it happening only for your app/site or all other apps/sites are having the same problem with IE 11 ?

Comment: only in one .aspx page with modal.

Comment: Please provide code. We are not psychic

Comment: Don't just provide code. Provide an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: <asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="Group" CssClass="form-control" Enabled="True"  onChange="javascript:loadDat();">
<asp:ListItem Text="Select a Field Group..." />
</asp:DropDownList>